# ReactJs.NET integration with Semantic UI React

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, reactjs.net

I am trying to use semnatic-ui-react with ReactJs.Net and I have an error around the minified script.

I have posted and issue here: https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/777 and hopefully somebody can help.

This is the stack trace
[image: This is the stack trace]